# Load more stuck at loading view - RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement the logic of load more in recycler view from [here](https://www.journaldev.com/24041/android-recyclerview-load-more-endless-scrolling)

it works well with me showing/hiding the loading indicator, but, when last load more list is empty (size = 0 ) It doesn't work and stuck at loading because the `notifyItemRangeInserted` not work as the size is zero.

so can anyone help me please?

adapter code:

```
public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private List<NotificationModel> notifications;

    private final int VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private final int VIEW_TYPE_LOADING = 1;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public NotificationAdapter(Context context, List<NotificationModel> notifications) {
        this.context = context;
        this.notifications = notifications;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ITEM) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_notification, viewGroup, false);
            return new CustomViewHolder(view);
        } else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_loading, viewGroup, false);
            return new LoadingViewHolder(view);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return notifications.size() - 1 == position ? VIEW_TYPE_LOADING : VIEW_TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        if (viewHolder instanceof CustomViewHolder) {
            populateItemRows((CustomViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
        } else if (viewHolder instanceof LoadingViewHolder) {
            showLoadingView((LoadingViewHolder) viewHolder, position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return notifications == null ? 0 : notifications.size();
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView notification_time, notification_body;

        public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            notification_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_time);
            notification_body = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_body);
        }
    }

    private void showLoadingView(LoadingViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        //ProgressBar would be displayed
        viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    private void populateItemRows(CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
             // row logic here
    }

    private class LoadingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        AVLoadingIndicatorView progressBar;

        public LoadingViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        }
    }
}
```

logic for refresh adapter with new data:

```
               // notificationsList is the adapter data source where i append new data
               if (notifications != null) {
                  int currentSize = notificationsList.size();
                  notificationsList.addAll(notifications);
                  notificationAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(currentSize, notifications.size());
               }
```

**the issue occurs when updating the adapter using `notifyItemRangeInserted` and new data size = 0**

Comment: You can check for `size`, if `size` is zero do not call `notifyItemRangeInserted`

Comment: I tried this option and didn't work

Comment: are you seeing same issue or a different issue?

Comment: different issue

Comment: what is the new issue now?

Comment: not new issue, the same but i just checked the Q and saw ur comment